# Casting Namespace

Tags: c#-4.0

I have class name called "Address" in two namespaces. Its been two EDMX files, so it holds
different namespace in client side. I have another class "Vendor" and it holds object of "Address" class. In one situation i have to convert  from one namespace to another namespace. 
How i can achieve this.

Comment: You do not *cast* namespaces, you resolve types by qualifying them with a namespace.

Comment: Yes, i know that this is design flaw and all the damages are done already. There is no way to change at this point of time. This has plenty of other class instance also. So assigning each and every property by ourself is painful job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not *cast* namespaces, you **resolve types** by **qualifying** them with a **namespace**.

Generally it is a **bad idea** to have multiple classes with the same name, especially **if they are used together** somewhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible automatically. Namespace is really just a prefix of name of class. Essentially they are completely different classes with nothing in common.

Answer (score 0):

Unless one Address class is derived from the other one, you cannot cast between the two at all. What you can do is give the classes some kind of "conversion constructor" that takes an object of the respective other class and maps the fields to its own ones:

```
namespace NS1
{
    public class Address
    {
        // fields go here

        public Address(NS2.Address add2)
        {
            this.Name = add2.Name;
            this.Street = add2.Street;

            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting namespace is conceptually incorrect.  It’s more appropriate to say casting from one type to another.  Unless the two classes are related in terms of inheritance, you cannot use casting at all.